# Get values from textfields in tablerow titanium

Tags: textfield, titanium-alloy

Hi i'm a beginner with titanium and i would like to get the value from textfields
in a tablerow

my view

```
<Alloy>
<Collection src="field"/>
<Window id="addWin" title="Add Name" class="container" modal="true">
    <TableView id="textfield" dataCollection="field">
        <TableViewRow>
            <TextField class="insertField" hintText="{field_description}"/>
        </TableViewRow>
    </TableView>  
    <Button onClick="addForm">Add form</Button>
</Window>
```

And my controller

```
function addForm() {
 while (fieldlist.isValidRow())
 {
   var field_description = fieldlist.fieldByName('field_description');

   if(field_description == 'name') {
        var contact = Alloy.createModel('contact', {
            name : $.insertField.value,
        });
   }
   fieldlist.next();
 }  
contacts.add(contact, {silent:true});
contact.save();
closeWindow();
}
```

I need to filter my insertField.value to get just one textfield from my form but i don't know how to do it. It return something like Cannot read property 'value' of undefined.
I think i need to loop it but i don't how.

Thanks if you help me

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have the view file static ( as pasted by you ) , I will suggest to add an **id** to the TextField.
Something like :

```
<TextField class="insertField" id="myTextField" hintText="{field_description}"/>
```

Then get the value of TextField as :

```
var myTextFieldValue = $.myTextField.getValue();
```